# How to publish an FS2 Stream generated by Doobie to Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, fs2, doobie

I want to publish a long list of events into Kafka consuming an fs2.Stream that corresponds to a very big list of DB rows that will eventually cause an Out Of Memotry error if compiled to List.

So, let's say that I have a - very big - list of UUID keys with millions of records:

```scala
def getKeyStream(timeRangeEnd: LocalDateTime): fs2.Stream[doobie.ConnectionIO, UUID]
```

and that I want to publish an event into Kafka corresponding to a *chunk* of 500 keys using this Publisher:

```scala
trait KeyPublisher {
  def publish(event: ChunkOfKeys): IO[Long]
}
```

I would like to create a function to enqueue/publish this stream into Kafka:

```scala
def enqueueKeyStreamIntoKafka(endDateTime: LocalDateTime): IO[Unit] = {
  getKeyStream(endDateTime)
     .chunkN(500)
     .evalMap(myChunk => ?????)
     ...
}
```

**How can I consume the stream originated by the DB, split it into chunks of constant size, and then publish each of them into Kafka?**

It's quite hard to find good documentation or examples about this topic apparently. Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Not sure what the question is? Do you know how to publish a single element into kafka? Do you know how to publish a batch of elements into kafka? If so, the just do that on that `evalMap` if not, then everything in this question is unnecessary.

Comment: Normally, I would compile the stream coming from the DB to map over it as a List (in memory) and then I would use `publish()` to push one or more elements to Kafka. So, I know how to do that. Now I need to use FS2 streams and I came here to gather information or even an example of what can be done.

Comment: It can, it's literally a one-liner, which is why @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ask what is the problem. It's something like `valuesFromDB.evalMap(publishSingeEvent).drain.compile` or `valuesFromDB.through(publishEventSink).drain.compile` depending on the exact implementations and signatures.

Comment: So you can convert a chuck into list, so you can just do that and then publish that list to kafka inside the `evalMap`, to finally `compile.drain` and that would give you an **IO[Unit]** that is sending the data in batches to kafka and you would be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't say what type `ChunkOfKeys` is, I'm going to assume it's something like `Chunk[UUID]`

```scala
def enqueueKeyStreamIntoKafka(endDateTime: LocalDateTime)(
    xa: Transactor[IO],
    publisher: KeyPublisher
): IO[Unit] =
  getKeyStream(endDateTime)
    .transact(xa) // Convert the ConnectionIO stream to Stream[IO, UUID]
    .chunkN(500)  // into Stream[IO, Chunk[UUID]]
    .evalMap(publisher.publish)  // Into Stream[IO, Long]
    .compile
    .drain // An IO[Unit] that describes the whole process
```